# TableSelect with drag-and-drop weight

Tags: 7, forms

I have a tableselect and I have been looking all over the internet for a tutorial on how to make a tableselect have sorting/drag-and-drop functionality. I have found tutorials for making normal lists have click and drag, but not a single mention of tableselect.

I would like to know if making a tableselect draggable is possible. I'm not asking for a tutorial. At this time I just want to know if it is possible.

This the form element I am using.

```
$form['mod_setttings']['settings'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#empty' => t('No settings available')
);
```

This tableselect is inside a vertical_tabs element.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for tabledrag option.If so please refer  [drupal_add_tabledrag](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7)

Comment: The documentation page has just an example for a table, while the OP is expressly asking for a *tableselect* form element.

Answer (score 0):

check these examples :

[Drupal: Drag and Drop Tables in Custom Modules](https://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/drupal-drag-and-drop-tables-in-custom-modules)

[CREATING A FORM WITH DRAGGABLE ELEMENTS](http://www.curveagency.com/blog/creating-form-draggable-elements-using-drupaladdtabledrag)

Comment: Neither links are for a *tableselect* form element.

Answer (score 0):

Without writing your code, you cannot.
To make a table (which isn't a form element) draggable, you first call `theme('table')` and then [`drupal_add_tabledrag()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7). With a *tableselect* form element, you don't call `theme('table')`, so you cannot call `drupal_add_tabledrag()` either.

What you could do is implementing a new form element and, in the theme function associated to that form element, call `theme('table')` and then `drupal_add_tabledrag()`. `theme_tableselect()` code can be used as guideline.

```
function theme_tableselect($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $rows = array();
  $header = $element['#header'];
  if (!empty($element['#options'])) {

    // Generate a table row for each selectable item in #options.
    foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
      $row = array();
      $row['data'] = array();
      if (isset($element['#options'][$key]['#attributes'])) {
        $row += $element['#options'][$key]['#attributes'];
      }

      // Render the checkbox / radio element.
      $row['data'][] = drupal_render($element[$key]);

      // As theme_table only maps header and row columns by order, create the
      // correct order by iterating over the header fields.
      foreach ($element['#header'] as $fieldname => $title) {
        $row['data'][] = $element['#options'][$key][$fieldname];
      }
      $rows[] = $row;
    }

    // Add an empty header or a "Select all" checkbox to provide room for the
    // checkboxes/radios in the first table column.
    if ($element['#js_select']) {

      // Add a "Select all" checkbox.
      drupal_add_js('misc/tableselect.js');
      array_unshift($header, array(
        'class' => array(
          'select-all',
        ),
      ));
    }
    else {

      // Add an empty header when radio buttons are displayed or a "Select all"
      // checkbox is not desired.
      array_unshift($header, '');
    }
  }
  return theme('table', array(
    'header' => $header,
    'rows' => $rows,
    'empty' => $element['#empty'],
    'attributes' => $element['#attributes'],
  ));
}
```

Keep in mind the conditions reported in [`drupal_add_tabledrag()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7) for the dragging to work, including that the table must have an ID attribute which must be equal to the first argument passed to `drupal_add_tabledrag()`, and each table row needs a weight value (which is used to sort the rows).